# DataGrid SelectedItem and CurrentItem on row change and on loosing focus

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Window which contains **two UserControls**. One has the address details the other shows the addresses in a DataGrid. When a new row is selected the addresses in the details view needs to be synchronized.

[image]

To synchronize the two UserControls I use the `CurrentCellChanged` event. There a method is called (`Sync_UserControl_Address_Base`) which synchronizes the data.

Because within the `CurrentCellChanged` event the property `DataGrid.SelectedItem` points to the Item before the row change I use for synchronizing the `DataGrid.CurrentItem` property.

When the `DataGrid` looses the focus the `CurrentCellChanged` event is fired and `DataGrid.CurrentItem` is null while `DataGrid.SelectedItem` points to the correct Item.

I use this code to handle this. When DataGrid.CurrentItem == null I use DataGrid.SelectedItem instead and it seems to work fine.

```
private void UserControl_AddressGrid_Base_DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null == this._ucAddressGridBase.CurrentItem)
        this.Sync_UserControl_Address_Base(this._ucAddressGridBase.SelectedItem);
    else
        this.Sync_UserControl_Address_Base(this._ucAddressGridBase.CurrentItem);
}
```

Have I overseen something or is this a proper way to handle it?

Comment: You should be using mvvm and just binding to the selecteditem of a collection.  No events.

Comment: You are right. Binding to the SelectedItem should be the better way. But here I can't use MVVM and have to code it manually in code behind.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle Why can't you use MVVM? You'd be better off programmatically creating Bindings and calling SetBinding on controls than trying to do it this way.

Comment: I agree that using bindings is the better way to solve my problem. But I need to create it using the `new Binding() ...` stuff in code behind. The reason is, that this code is the result of a code generator where the developer defines the datatables, grids etc. in an interactive environment and the generator creates the complete code without any xaml. It's very mighty but no xaml can be used there.

Comment: I prefer building xaml as strings and xamlreader.parse into ui if I'm building ui dynamically. Not sure what you're doing here exactly but you can grab such xaml and stick it into a scratch app to troubleshoot. If you build everything in code and it goes wrong then it can be a right nuisance just working out what's up.

Comment: @Andy Full ack, but I can't change it here. Don't know if my question is worth to be kept. If you think so, I would accept your "use an binding instead" comment as answer. Otherwise I will delete it. :-)

Comment: There may be some value in the question for others, so I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using events, you're almost always best using binding and MVVM instead.
In this case, the usual approach would be to bind the selected item to a property in a window level viewmodel.  This would be the datacontext of the window both usercontrols are in and hence inherited to both usercontrols. Then bind the datacontext of the second usercontrol ( or a panel within it ) to that property.

Since this is two usercontrols, you cannot bind the datacontext of the second control directly to the selector in the first because it'll be a private member.  It's also often a requirement to do something when selection changes and if you have that selected item property in the viewmodel then you can potentially drive logic from it's setter.